# Creating a temporary table within a TRIGGER with GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I need to create and use a temporary table with `GROUP BY` clause within a trigger, but I'm having difficulties doing so.

**My attempt:**

Here I'm trying to use two temporary tables which are dropped after the trigger reach an end.

First I create a `#Temptable` and the trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (admID smallint, diagID smallint);

CREATE TRIGGER tr_newTest
ON Adm_Diag
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
...
END
```

Since the table inserted only contains rows for a current `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements I'm passing several `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements to `#TempTable`.

```
DECLARE @admID smallint
SELECT @admID = Adm_ID
FROM inserted

DECLARE @diagID smallint
SELECT @diagID=Diag_ID
FROM inserted

INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES (@admID, @diagID)
```

Now with this data I want to create a temporary table that groups the rows of `#TempTable`:

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempGroupTable
FROM
(
    SELECT admID, COUNT(*) as Diag
    FROM #TempTable
    GROUP BY admID
) t1
WHERE Diag > 2
```

The whole script

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (admID smallint, diagID smallint);

CREATE TRIGGER tr_newTest
ON Adm_Diag
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @admID smallint
    SELECT @admID = Adm_ID
    FROM inserted

    DECLARE @diagID smallint
    SELECT @diagID=Diag_ID
    FROM inserted

    INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES (@admID, @diagID)

    -- Below I'm tring to create #TempGroupTable

    SELECT *
    INTO #TempGroupTable
    FROM
    (
        SELECT admID, COUNT(*) as Diag
        FROM #TempTable
        GROUP BY admID
    ) t1
    WHERE Diag > 2

END
```

After executing the trigger I get an error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 41 Invalid object name
>   '#TempGroupTable'.

How can I create `#TempGroupTable`?

Comment: Why aren't you using physical table instead of temp table. Temp table with `#` will not work outside of session.

Comment: @TanjimRahman I don't need to work with temp tables outside the session. As I said, only for the duration of the trigger.

Comment: Use a double pound sign, `##TempGroupTable`

Comment: While your trigger is working it will not get single `#` temp tables. Either you use physical table or use `##` as @Rene said.

Comment: Your trigger is broken. Triggers in SQL Server execute once per *statement*, not once per row. This means that `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. Which means statements like `SELECT @diagID=Diag_ID
    FROM inserted` are horribly misguided because they a) ignore all but one row and b) are not even guaranteed (when you use multiple such statements) to select values from the same row.

Comment: @Jazz this code, the idea and accepted answer do smell very bad. Unless it's just for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quote sure what you are trying to do but would a global temporary tables which starts with `##` work for you? So make the `#TempGroupTable` into `##TempGroupTable`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not dispense with all the overhead of temp tables and variables? Try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_newTest
ON Adm_Diag
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Adm_Diag (adminID, Diag)
SELECT admID, COUNT(*) as Diag
FROM inserted
GROUP BY admID

END
```